# What will be my Provident Fund withdrawal amount for 8 months?

Tags: india, retirement-plan

I have worked with a company for 8 months. Now I want my Provident Fund. I have applied to withdraw my PF, but don't know what amount I will get. My Provident Fund balance is EE-7170 and ER- 2189.

Answer (score 1):

It would be EE+ER, 7170 and 2189. The PF should apply the interest for the balances at the end of each month. This may already have been reflected, if not you may get some more as interest.